# Post and Receive Result

Tags: java, android, spring, spring-boot

Android space

```
void post(Food food)
{
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String jsonFood = gson.toJson(food);

    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());

    restTemplate.postForEntity(URL, jsonFood, String.class);
}
```

Back end space

```
@PostMapping("/food")
public void postFood(@RequestBody String foodJson)
{
    Food food = new GsonBuilder().create().fromJson(foodJson, Food.class);

    String id = createId(food);
    // now how do I send back saying I got this and here is an id?

}
```

After I receive I want to reply back saying I got the information and send back an ID.

Answer (score 1):

Spring boot will automatically convert the json to a model object under the covers using Jackson

```
@PostMapping("/food")
public YourResponse postFood(@RequestBody Food food)
{
    String id = createId(food);
    return new YourResponse(id,"hello World");
}
```

Response object

```
 public class YourResponse{
       private String id;
       private String response;
       //.. constructor, getter setter
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a response model

```
    public class PostFoodResponse{
       private String id;
       private String response;
       //.. constructor, getter setter
    }
```

In your code create an object of PostFoodResponse set data and send the object back as a json response

```
@PostMapping("/food")
public String postFood(@RequestBody String foodJson)
{
    Food food = new GsonBuilder().create().fromJson(foodJson, Food.class);

    String id = createId(food);
    // now how do I send back saying I got this and here is an id?
    PostFoodResponse response = new PostFoodResponse(id, "I got this");
    return new GsonBuilder().create().toJson(response);

}
```

Comment: The sending back as a response, how do I do that?

Comment: And on the client side how do I get the response? Sorry if this is so obvious.

Comment: which network library are you using for android?
Parse the json data into your android application from the network response.
give your network library's documentation a read to learn more